# last query result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT sma_quotes.customer as name, 
       sma_quotes.date as date, 
       sma_quotes.selecttype as type, 
       sma_quotes.biller_id as bl_id, 
       sma_quotes.volume as volume, 
       sma_quotes.containernumber as cn_no, 
       sma_quotes.grand_total as total, 
       sma_sales.paid as paid 
FROM sma_quotes 
     JOIN sma_sales ON sma_sales.quote_id = sma_quotes.id 
WHERE name IS 'Everbest Foods'
```

Error
SQL query: Documentation

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Everbest Foods' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: Given the error you are reporting, you must have missed part of the SQL statement because there is no LIMIT in the query. Perhaps you could post all of it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LIMIT` in your query, so the error message is suspicious.

However, you want `=`, not `IS`:

```
WHERE sma_quotes.customer = 'Everbest Foods'
```

Comment: one question - is it allowed to use allias `name` in `WHERE` clause? Shouldn't it be `sma_quotes.customer` instead of just `name` ?

Comment: @demo . . . It depends.  If the OP intends for that to be the reference, then yes (and that is very likely so I changed the answer).  On the other hand, `name` could be a valid column in one of the tables, although it should really be qualified with the table name.